# Are there any tools that can monitor SNMP, JMX & TIBCO Hawk in one place?

Tags: monitoring, jmx, tibco

Our Operations department is getting twitchy about too many monitoring tools so are there any tools that can handle SNMP, JMX and TIBCO Hawk all in one application?

Comment: SO is for programming related questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SNMP & JMX are monitored by a product Manage Engine Applications Manager. You can give it a try.Regarding Tibco Hawk am also in search of a tool.Do let me know if you find one,.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, your system administrators want a single console that can handle, Hawk, JMX and SNMP.

Hawk Console can do this because Hawk agents can bridge JMX and SNMP (if you use the additional Hawk SNMP adapter).

Alternatively, if you prefer a different console then there are two common ways to get Hawk alerts to that console:

1. Use the Hawk SNMP Adapter to convert Hawk alerts into SNMP traps. The adapter is seperately licensed.
2. Run Hawk Alert Server (bundled with Hawk) which persists Hawk alerts to a logfile, then get your console to trawl the logfile.

Answer (score 1):

Try to look at the Mirador software from those Swiss guys:

http://www.centeractive.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=12&Itemid=7&lang=en

Extensive hawk support

Answer (score 0):

What about SL Corporation's RTView product ?
It handles SNMP, JMX, and all the TIBCO products